# Virtualenv is taken the wrong version of python - Red Hat

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, redhat

I've got python 3.6 installed with redhat 8 (this version of python comes by default) and I've installed python 3.7.4 later on.

When I build a virtualenv the virtualenv takes the version python 3.6.
This is my command to create a virtualenv:

```
$ sudo virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 app_virtual -p python3
$ source app_virtual/bin/activate
```

I tried to delete python3.6 from RedHat but I couldn't and I also tried to make the version 3.7 as main with

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

and this is where python versions are:

```
$ whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib64/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/local/bin/python3.7-config /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz /usr/src/Python-3.7.4/python
```

but nothing, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

For `virtualenv` options `--python` and `-p` are the same. In

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -p python3
```

1st you set python to `python3.7` and immediately overwrite it with `python3` which is most probably `python3.6` on your system. Just use one of the options, not both.

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.7 app_virtual
```

is enough. Or

```
virtualenv -p python3.7 app_virtual
```

PS. Don't use `sudo` with `virtualenv`. You seldom need `sudo` at all and never with with `virtualenv`.